# Data duplicates in Arraylist

Tags: java, sql, arraylist, jdb

I want to fill my ArrayList with data selected from my database but it duplicates all the rows i don't get it.

```
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userid, password);
        String strSql = "SELECT * FROM events, eventStats" ;
        PreparedStatement Stmt = conn.prepareStatement(strSql);
        ResultSet rs = Stmt.executeQuery(strSql);

        while(rs.next()){
            Events user = new Events();
            user.seteName(rs.getString(2));
            user.setePlace(rs.getString(4));
            user.seteDate(rs.getString(5));
            user.seteInscrit(String.valueOf(rs.getInt(8)));
            user.seteTotal(String.valueOf(rs.getFloat(10)));
            data.add(user);
        }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you try to run that query on your DBMS console?

Comment: the problem is in your query, not in your java code. fix it ( *JOIN* or *WHERE*) and you will get the correct result

Comment: Are you sure there are no duplicates in the `ResultSet` already? Things like that may happen if you select from two or more tables without joining or putting proper `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Maybe, you can get around this problem by simply adding `DISTINCT` to your query. Please try `"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM events, eventStats"` and/or try to match their primary keys or anything. **AND READ THE ANSWER given by JonK**.

Comment: `DISTINCT` wouldn't help in this case because the OP is selecting all of the columns from both tables, so each row will be unique anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually seeing 'duplicate' rows in the strictest sense of the word.

What you're seeing is a **Cartesian Product**, which is every row in one table joined to *every single row* in another table. You're getting this because you've got a cartesian join (or a cross-join if you prefer) in your SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM events, eventStats
--            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This means that for each row in the `events` table, you will get a number of results equal to the number of rows in the `eventStats` table. Add that all together and what looks like a lot of duplicates is actually a potentially huge number of unique combinations of all of the rows from both tables lumped together.

There are a select number of scenarios where a cartesian join is desirable, however it is very often an indicator of a faulty query, and can have a huge performance impact on your system if one of the tables is particularly large.<sup>1</sup>

To avoid it you will need to specify which column in each of your tables to use to join the two tables together, either through an explicit join:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM events v
       [INNER|LEFT OUTER|RIGHT OUTER] JOIN eventStats s
         ON v.SomeColumn = s.SomeMatchingColumn
```

or an implicit one:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM events v, eventStats s
 WHERE v.SomeColumn = s.SomeMatchingColumn
```

It's hard to tell you more than that without seeing the table structure, but there is probably a foreign key relationship between those two tables, and that's the column that you want to join on.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The number of rows that a cartesian join will return is equal to the the product of the sizes of the tables involved in the join. As an example, say the `events` table contains 50,000 rows and the `eventStats` table also has 50,000 rows, one for each `event`. With a cartesian join on those tables your query will return a whopping *2,500,000,000*, yes, that's 2.5 *billion*, rows of data. Now imagine reading all of that into an `ArrayList`... except you can't, because Java arrays can't get that large! Your application will crash with either a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit` or a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` before you can read all the data in.</sub>

Comment: thanks for you help dude you fixed my problem i needed to join both table. Thx to all of u